# How can I install Windows Live Essentials 2011 from behind a proxy?

Tags: windows-live-messenger, instant-messaging

I need to install Windows Live Essentials on Windows 7 64-bit. I'm behind the company proxy but in Internet Options everything is set up to work with the proxy.

When I start the setup file: `wlsetup-web.exe` it says it can't connect but there is no option to tell it what the proxy is. Our sysadmin configures everything in `Internet Options/Connections`.

How can I install Windows Live Essentials 2011 from behind a proxy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try the full-setup from [here](http://www.mydigitallife.info/download-windows-live-essentials-with-messenger-2011-final-full-version-offline-installer/) to install it without using the internet during the setup.

Comment: do you happen to have a non german version? Maybe english or italian?

Comment: I am sorry for this, I thought the installer was a multi language one. I updated the link to a better page.